# How do I retrieve Haystack SearchQuery parameters

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-haystack

I am looking for a way to serialize a Haystack search query (not the query results) so that I can reconstruct it later.  Is there a way to do this without having to intercept the parameters from off of the `request` object?

For context, I want users to be able to subscribe to the results of a particular search, including any new results that may pop up over time.

**Edit:**

I settled on storing the search with:

```
filter = queryset.query.query_filter
```

and then loading this back in using:

```
SearchQuerySet().raw_search(filter)
```

Though I suspect this will tie me to whichever particular search back-end I'm using now.  Is this true?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the query in your request.GET. Then it should be fairly easy to construct a [RSS Feed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/syndication/) using that query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It is true that the parameters are going to be in my request.GET; I was just hoping that I would be able to find a single string representation of the search query (filters, facets, and all) that I could store, load, and run again.